# How do you rig an armature with automatic weights without it getting deformed?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, tracking

I am trying to rig my armature with automatic weights to a download of a 3d facemodel. I already uploaded the tracking data and when I parent the rig to the mesh, it becomes badly deformed. Yet the bones parent and the face tracking animation works. So it slightly works but I want to figure out how to parent the bones to the face without it deforming so badly. Is there a way to parent it so it doesn't deform so badly? I will attach the file. You can see in the photos I uploaded the difference between the rest mesh and the mesh after it has been attached with weights to the rid. I did notice that the bones move to different spots when toggling the rig between object and edit mode. Maybe the bones aren't set in the proper position? I was following a tutorial where a guy animates his own face with tracking, but I am doing another persons face and because of that I used bone offset because our faces are differnt shapes. I am not sure if that helps. Here is a link to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNK8S19OSmA).

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/my2hzr7669fzr0d/HelloAndWelcomeFaceTracking.blend?dl=0

Thank you,

Andrew

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: please apply scale before parenting to rig. does that help?

Comment: @Chris I tried doing this and it did not help :(
but I added more information to the question. I hope this helps to make the problem more clear. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @Chris I found the answer, or at lease part of it. I did not think this would play a role, but the size of the bone can affect the deformation of the mesh. I resolved this issue by toggling between edit and pose mode, rearranging the bones to the original default position, and then I edited the size of the bones until they matched the shape of the original mesh. I recomend for anyone reading this that you make sure that all the bones are uniform size before applying the automatic weights and then rearrange them back to the original pose postion-Answer bone size and position in pose and rest

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, or at lease part of it. I did not think this would play a role, but the size of the bone can affect the deformation of the mesh. I resolved this issue by toggling between edit and pose mode, rearranging the bones to the original default position, and then I edited the size of the bones until they matched the shape of the original mesh. I recommend for anyone reading this that you make sure that all the bones are uniform size before applying the automatic weights, and then rearrange them back to the original pose postion after applying the bones with automatic weights.

Short Answer: bone size and position in pose and rest mode before automatic wight application are critical to automatically rigging a mesh without badly deforming it